# Gitlab CE 500 error after upgrade / downgrade

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ce

I have a Gitlab CE server version 13.10 which was found updated by mistake during a system update to a version 14.8.

With these version, i get a 500 error for all pages.

So I downgraded to version 13.10.5 and I was able to use my Gitlab server again.

However, wanting to create a new group I again had a 500 error:

```
Started GET "/groups/new" for 62.34.67.75 at 2022-04-19 17:23:00 +0200
Processing by GroupsController#new as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 78ms (ActiveRecord: 4.2ms | Elasticsearch: 0.0ms | Allocations: 27029)
  
ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "services" does not exist
LINE 8:  WHERE a.attrelid = '"services"'::regclass
```

Apparently this error seems to be database related.

I tried to upgrade one version up by installing version 13.11.7 and again all pages lead to a 500 error with the same error as above.

any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
After searching in Google it seem's that the `integrations` table was renamed to `services`: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/blob/master/db/post_migrate/20210621223242_finalize_rename_services_to_integrations.rb

After taking a look to database schema on my server the `integrations` is still existing.

So it's like database is still in a ahead version and database donwngrade not ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this error by using `gitlab-psql` to execute this query:

```
ALTER TABLE Integrations RENAME TO Services;
```

By renaming the `Integrations` table to `services` the problem disappear.

Comment: This is strongly not recommended to anyone else who has this problem. By manually running `ALTER TABLE`, you would bring your GitLab installation to an inconsistent state from which you will not be able to migrate. The other answer by @sytech links to the documentation that explains the GitLab upgrade path. My workaround for the error `relation "services" does not exist` was to upgrade to 14.1.1.

Comment: @user2468842 Just read the original post and you'll see that this problem occured in a specific case, just read again. 
The problem arrive during a 13.8 to 14.10 upgrade. 
The upgrade path is 13.12.15 -> 14.0.12 -> 14.3.6 -> 14.8.6.
As respecting the upgrade path is required, what you recommend is not possible.
This solution is working and there is no problem to workaround like this.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot update directly to 14.8 from 13.10 otherwise you will be missing certain database migrations. You are likely to discover many more features of GitLab will be broken in unexpected ways if you skip versions in the [upgrade path](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/#upgrade-paths).

You must follow the [upgrade path](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/#upgrade-paths). Meaning in your case, you should upgrade first to `13.12.15` then to `14.0.12` then to `14.x.y` (e.g. 14.8). Also be sure to let all background migrations complete and pay attention to version specific notes (especially [in 14.0](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/#1400)) before moving onto the next version.

The problem you are experiencing may be fixable by running the database operations manually, but this is not recommended. The best option is to follow the upgrade path to make sure all migrations happen correctly and in the correct order.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But as I said in my question this update was done accidentally during a server update.

As I put in my auto answer, renaming the integrations table to services fixed the problem.

Comment: I guess that's a problem (we) newbies do, we use docker hub latest official gitlab image thinking that updates will be smoother and not following this update path. What to do in such a cases?

Comment: @juagicre you probably want to avoid using the `latest` tag. Whenever you upgrade gitlab, you need to check the docs for any [upgrade path](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/index.html#upgrade-paths) requirements and for any [version specific upgrade instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/index.html#version-specific-upgrading-instructions) you may need to follow.

Comment: @sytech that's clear now, which is too late, so what can somebody do to solve a wrong update? by the way I think gitlab should have a check for this and prevent any action at all when this happens...

Comment: @juagicre I agree GitLab should have a check for this -- or just always do the right thing when you use the latest image. I'm not sure why they do not. But if it's already too late, my recommendation would be to restore from a backup taken before the upgrade, then follow the correct path. I'm not sure if there's a less disruptive way to fix this. GitLab support may be able to help in such a case; it probably requires precise knowledge of the migrations and reason for needing the specific upgrade path for the particular version(s) at issue.

Comment: @sytech, thanks for the hint! I'll need to ask for specific tech support as I did not do a backup of my data and config before the update 